# Unexpected behavior with named Docker NFS volumes in a Swarm cluster

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, nfs

I'm new to Docker Swarm and I'm managing all config via Ansible. I have a four-node Swarm cluster with the following members

- manager (also the NFS exporter for volumes shared across the cluster)
- cluster0
- cluster1
- cluster2

cluster[0-2] are workers in the swarm.

I'm configuring a service which makes use of a named volume `media`, which is an NFS export from `manager`. The service is constrained to the worker nodes. Once a service is deployed that makes use of this volume, I'd expect to see the following output of `docker volume inspect media` from any of the worker nodes with the replicated service:

```
user@cluster1:~ $ docker volume inspect media 
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-01-27T12:23:55-08:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/media/_data",
        "Name": "media",
        "Options": {
            "device": ":/path/media",
            "o": "addr=manager.domain.com,rw",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

and indeed when I `docker volume inspect media` from the swarm manager, I see:

```
user@manager:~$ docker volume inspect media 
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-11-22T07:58:55-08:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/media/_data",
        "Name": "media",
        "Options": {
            "device": ":/path/media",
            "o": "addr=manager.domain.com,rw",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

However, this is the output I see from the nodes with the replicated service:

```
user@cluster1:~ $ docker volume inspect media       
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-11-22T07:59:02-08:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/media/_data",
        "Name": "media",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

As a result, I'm unable to access the NFS-exported files. I'm not entirely sure how to troubleshoot. Is this a limitation of Swarm and if so, how are others working around this issue? If not, what am I missing?